# Responsive mixins width vs device width

Tags: html, css

I use the following responsive mixin in sass:

```
@mixin macbook-pro {
  @media (min-width: #{$macbook-pro-width}) and (max-width: #{$desktop-width - 1px}) {
    @content;
  }
}
```

However, I set breakpoints where the font size changes. For example, at a 1920 browser width, the font size is 18px. As the browser decreases in width, the font size becomes 14px eventually (to accommodate smaller screen resolutions). How can I make sure that the font size stays the same as the browser width changes, but when the screen resolution changes, the font size changes.

So basically, I want it so that when the browser width is 1920px with screen resolution of 1920, the font size if 18px. As you make the window smaller, the font size stays at 18px.

However, when the screen resolution is 1440px and the browser width is 1440px, the font size is 14px. As you make the window smaller, the font size stays the same at that screen resolution.

I tried using device-min-width instead of min-width, but I'm guessing there are some downsides to using that.

Answer (score 0):

What units are you currently using for your font size?

Unless I'm misunderstanding you should be able to just set the font size in a media query for each resolution.

Are you using px, or percentage based sizing?